# Short-term internship visa issued by Austria - what to do if no work-related remark is present on sticker?

Tags: schengen-visas, austria, working-visas

I recently got my Schengen short stay visa approved to travel to Austria for an internship for less than 90 days. However my comments / remark section on my visa sticker is just blank. No remarks. I expected to see something like "[ERWERB](https://oead.at/en/to-austria/scholars/before-arrival/entry-conditions/nationals-from-third-countries-for-stays-of-up-to-6-months/)" written on it to show ability to get gainful employment (due to my internship).

What should I do to ensure I can complete my internship?

Comment: I realize this is two years later, but did you figure this out? I have the same question.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, I now know the answer to this for anyone reading in the future: The Austrian Consulate made a mistake. You must contact them and send your passport back so they can fix the visa sticker by adding "ERWERB".

Comment: Hey I'm glad you got this sorted out. I think I called the embassy or something back then but nothing tangible came off it. I also called the 3rd party handling it and nothing could be done. So I traveled for my internship anyway, reported to the local office in Salzburg (Austria) for documentation as a foreigner and all that, nobody said anything about the missing remark. So I went ahead with my internship and finished it. Also met the Austrian Ambassador to Malta and Nigerian Ambassador to Austria in person during my internship. I was worried about the ERWERB remark but it didn't limit me.

Comment: Sounds like a cool internship! Yeah, the University HR staff told me that they definitely would not be able to employ me without the ERWERB remark so I'm glad the consulate agreed to fix it.